# программа не видит файл который должна прочитать

Tags: golang

Недавно начал изучение golang по книге Head first go, написанной Jay McGavren. Там был пример кода, который позволял читать числа с текстового файла. Но как бы я не старался, каждый раз возникает ошибка:
"open data.txt: The system cannot find the file specified.
exit status 1".
С переменной средой GOPATH всё в порядке, файл существует. Вот собственно сам код и пакет "github.com/headfirstgo/datafile":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/headfirstgo/datafile"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    numbers, err := datafile.GetFloats("data.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var sum float64 = 0
    for _, number := range numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    sampleCount := float64(len(numbers))
    srw := sum / sampleCount
    fmt.Printf("Average: %0.2f\n", srw)
}

package datafile

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

// GetFloats читает значение float64 из каждой строки файла.
func GetFloats(fileName string) ([3]float64, error) {
    var numbers [3]float64
    file, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        return numbers, err
    }
    i := 0
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        numbers[i], err = strconv.ParseFloat(scanner.Text(), 64)
        if err != nil {
            return numbers, err
        }
        i++
    }
    err = file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return numbers, err
    }
    if scanner.Err() != nil {
        return numbers, scanner.Err()
    }
    return numbers, nil
}
```

Comment: напишите: какая OS и полный путь файлу data.txt, и из какой папки или каким образом запускаете, все это так или иначе может влиять на то что файл будет не найден.

Comment: `github.com/headfirstgo/datafile` установлен как пакет? код полностью рабочий, проблема не воспроизводится

Comment: @DaniilLoban Здравствуйте, пользуюсь windows 10, компилятором VS Code. Пакет установлен в C:\Program Files\Go\src. Сам main.go находится в C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\headfirstgo\average.                                 
        C:\Program Files\Go\ ($GOROOT)
        D:\go-prog\ ($GOPATH), пробовал копировать data.txt в обе папки

Comment: пробовали помещать файл в `C:\Program Files\Go\src\github.com\headfirstgo\average\data.txt`?   `D:\go-prog` - что там находится?

Comment: Это переменные используются для работы компилятора и линкера Go, и никак не влияют на то, где ваша программа будет искать файлы. Используйте либо полный путь до файла, либо помещайте его в директорию, где находится исполняемый файл.